# iOS app rejected but bug cannot be reproduced

Tags: ios

My app has been rejected by Apple due to Facebook signup process which caused the app to crash.
However, this worked on all simulators and both real iPhone and iPad every time I tested my app.

Where should I start to fix that?

Here is the crash report from Apple:

```
    {"app_name":"Overseas Learning","timestamp":"2016-08-30 09:27:06.06    
    -0700","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"3d3ec90a-8117-3226-9979-5619441e6e79","adam_id":0,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.overseaslearning.OLapp","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 9.3.5 (13G36)","name":"Overseas Learning"}
    Incident Identifier: 580D6EF1-3637-4BE1-A2B3-6DCB2F3293AB
    CrashReporter Key:   9d29e1f6129da106e611e3ea092cd4a4365cdea9
    Hardware Model:      xxx
    Process:             Overseas Learning [405]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Overseas Learning
    Identifier:          com.overseaslearning.OLapp
    Version:             1 (1.0)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2016-08-30 09:27:06.06 -0700
    Launch Time:         2016-08-30 09:26:55.55 -0700
    OS Version:          iOS 9.3.5 (13G36)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
    9.285610     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001853d8f28 [0x14e091200] Decoding completed without errors
    9.289167     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001853d70c0 [0x14e091200] Options: 200x200 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
    9.289167     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001853d6f78 [0x14e091200] Decoding: C2 0x00C800C8 0x00003842 0x22111100 0x00000000 9596
    9.337166     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001853d626c [0x14e09ea00] Created session
    9.346843     AppleJPEG                  0x00000001853d626c [0x14e091200] Created session
    9.929360     CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f598e0 TCP Conn 0x14d668fd0 SSL Handshake DONE
    10.111551    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f597f0 TCP Conn 0x14d668fd0 starting SSL negotiation
    10.111877    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ffbe7c TCP Conn 0x14d668fd0 complete. fd: 10, err: 0
    10.113363    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ffd3a8 TCP Conn 0x14d668fd0 event 1. err: 0
    10.217048    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ffd480 TCP Conn 0x14d668fd0 started
    10.218241    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184057e5c Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
    10.218241    CFNetwork                  0x0000000184057e28 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    10.218241    CFNetwork                  0x00000001840a9e50 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    10.294730    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f598e0 TCP Conn 0x14d557690 SSL Handshake DONE
    10.334473    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183f597f0 TCP Conn 0x14d557690 starting SSL negotiation
    10.334820    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ffbe7c TCP Conn 0x14d557690 complete. fd: 5, err: 0
    10.335209    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ffd3a8 TCP Conn 0x14d557690 event 1. err: 0
    10.357109    CFNetwork                  0x0000000183ffd480 TCP Conn 0x14d557690 started



    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018351011c 0x1834f4000 + 114972
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835dcef8 0x1835d8000 + 20216
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000183481dc8 0x183420000 + 400840
    3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100c187c4 0x100a48000 + 1902532
    4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100c00fb0 0x100a48000 + 1806256
    5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100c01040 0x100a48000 + 1806400
    6   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100c2734c 0x100a48000 + 1962828
    7   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100c01c0c 0x100a48000 + 1809420
    8   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100c024f0 0x100a48000 + 1811696
    9   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100c0213c 0x100a48000 + 1810748
    10  Overseas Learning               0x00000001000ed1d8 0x100078000 + 479704
    11  Overseas Learning               0x0000000100094a44 0x100078000 + 117316
    12  Alamofire                       0x00000001001d2b40 0x100194000 + 256832
    13  Alamofire                       0x00000001001d57bc 0x100194000 + 268220
    14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833c14bc 0x1833c0000 + 5308
    15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833c147c 0x1833c0000 + 5244
    16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833c6b84 0x1833c0000 + 27524
    17  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018392cd50 0x18384c000 + 920912
    18  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018392abb8 0x18384c000 + 912312
    19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183854c50 0x18384c000 + 35920
    20  GraphicsServices                0x000000018513c088 0x185130000 + 49288
    21  UIKit                           0x0000000188b3a088 0x188abc000 + 516232
    22  Overseas Learning               0x00000001000ba798 0x100078000 + 272280
    23  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001833f28b8 0x1833f0000 + 10424

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache
    Thread 1:
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182fede08 0x182fd4000 + 105992
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182fe391c 0x182fd4000 + 63772
    2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182fedd78 0x182fd4000 + 105848
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183870fd8 0x18384c000 + 151512
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018385c9b4 0x18384c000 + 68020
    5   Foundation                      0x000000018425f930 0x184258000 + 31024
    6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839abc64 0x18384c000 + 1440868
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183850c34 0x18384c000 + 19508
    8   Foundation                      0x000000018425f8bc 0x184258000 + 30908
    9   Foundation                      0x000000018425f868 0x184258000 + 30824
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839abc64 0x18384c000 + 1440868
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018385e150 0x18384c000 + 74064
    12  Foundation                      0x000000018425f80c 0x184258000 + 30732
    13  Foundation                      0x000000018425fc30 0x184258000 + 31792
    14  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018360cf68 0x183608000 + 20328
    15  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018360a9b4 0x183608000 + 10676
    16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833c1578 0x1833c0000 + 5496
    17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833db2b8 0x1833c0000 + 111288
    18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833c4a2c 0x1833c0000 + 18988
    19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833cd694 0x1833c0000 + 54932
    20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833c4f80 0x1833c0000 + 20352
    21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833cf390 0x1833c0000 + 62352
    22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833cf0b0 0x1833c0000 + 61616
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9470 0x1835d8000 + 5232
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9020 0x1835d8000 + 4128

    Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001835114d8 0x1834f4000 + 120024
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833d47d8 0x1833c0000 + 83928
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001833c3648 0x1833c0000 + 13896

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183510b48 0x1834f4000 + 117576
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9530 0x1835d8000 + 5424
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9020 0x1835d8000 + 4128

    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183510b48 0x1834f4000 + 117576
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9530 0x1835d8000 + 5424
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9020 0x1835d8000 + 4128

    Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001834f4fd8 0x1834f4000 + 4056
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001834f4e54 0x1834f4000 + 3668
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018392cc60 0x18384c000 + 920672
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018392a964 0x18384c000 + 911716
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183854c50 0x18384c000 + 35920
    5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000183fd5bcc 0x183f28000 + 711628
    6   Foundation                      0x000000018434be4c 0x184258000 + 998988
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835dbb28 0x1835d8000 + 15144
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835dba8c 0x1835d8000 + 14988
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9028 0x1835d8000 + 4136

    Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
    Thread 6:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183510344 0x1834f4000 + 115524
    1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839331c8 0x18384c000 + 946632
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835dbb28 0x1835d8000 + 15144
    3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835dba8c 0x1835d8000 + 14988
    4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9028 0x1835d8000 + 4136

    Thread 7:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183510b48 0x1834f4000 + 117576
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9530 0x1835d8000 + 5424
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9020 0x1835d8000 + 4128

    Thread 8:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000183510b48 0x1834f4000 + 117576
    1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9530 0x1835d8000 + 5424
    2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9020 0x1835d8000 + 4128

    Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
    Thread 9:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001834f4fd8 0x1834f4000 + 4056
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001834f4e54 0x1834f4000 + 3668
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018392cc60 0x18384c000 + 920672
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018392a964 0x18384c000 + 911716
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183854c50 0x18384c000 + 35920
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001838a23a4 0x18384c000 + 353188
    6   CoreMotion                      0x000000018981f41c 0x1897cc000 + 341020
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835dbb28 0x1835d8000 + 15144
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835dba8c 0x1835d8000 + 14988
    9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001835d9028 0x1835d8000 + 4136

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
        x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000014d5dcbf0
        x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
        x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x00000001a40b7731
       x12: 0x00000001a40b7731  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x000000008000001f  x15: 0x0000000080000023
       x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000100c48040  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
       x20: 0x00000001a1bdd000  x21: 0x00000001a1be7378  x22: 0x000000016fd86788  x23: 0x000000016fd86770
       x24: 0x0000000100eccd30  x25: 0xa00000000005d5b2  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000001
       x28: 0x0000000100c37a66  fp: 0x000000016fd866c0   lr: 0x00000001835dcef8
        sp: 0x000000016fd866a0   pc: 0x000000018351011c cpsr: 0x00000000

    Binary Images:
    0x100078000 - 0x10012ffff Overseas Learning arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Overseas Learning
    0x100194000 - 0x1001f3fff Alamofire arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
    0x10025c000 - 0x100293fff AlamofireImage arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/AlamofireImage.framework/AlamofireImage
    0x1002d0000 - 0x1002d7fff AlamofireSwiftyJSON arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/AlamofireSwiftyJSON.framework/AlamofireSwiftyJSON
    0x100300000 - 0x100307fff BMCustomTableView arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/BMCustomTableView.framework/BMCustomTableView
    0x10031c000 - 0x100333fff Bolts arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework/Bolts
    0x10035c000 - 0x100367fff COBezierTableView arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/COBezierTableView.framework/COBezierTableView
    0x100378000 - 0x100387fff DZNEmptyDataSet arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/DZNEmptyDataSet.framework/DZNEmptyDataSet
    0x1003a4000 - 0x1003f7fff FBSDKCoreKit arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
    0x100420000 - 0x10043bfff FBSDKLoginKit arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit
    0x10045c000 - 0x1004bbfff FBSDKShareKit arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/FBSDKShareKit.framework/FBSDKShareKit
    0x1004e4000 - 0x1004f7fff FoldingCell arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/FoldingCell.framework/FoldingCell
    0x100508000 - 0x100513fff FontBlaster arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/FontBlaster.framework/FontBlaster
    0x10052c000 - 0x100583fff Former arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/Former.framework/Former
    0x1005f4000 - 0x100623fff Haneke arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/Haneke.framework/Haneke
    0x100658000 - 0x1006a3fff IQKeyboardManagerSwift arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/IQKeyboardManagerSwift.framework/IQKeyboardManagerSwift
    0x1006dc000 - 0x1006f7fff ImageSlideshow arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/ImageSlideshow.framework/ImageSlideshow
    0x100720000 - 0x10076bfff Kingfisher arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/Kingfisher.framework/Kingfisher
    0x1007a4000 - 0x1007c7fff Koloda arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/Koloda.framework/Koloda
    0x1007f0000 - 0x1007fffff MVCarouselCollectionView arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/MVCarouselCollectionView.framework/MVCarouselCollectionView
    0x100824000 - 0x100843fff PKHUD arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/PKHUD.framework/PKHUD
    0x100870000 - 0x10088ffff RAMAnimatedTabBarController arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/RAMAnimatedTabBarController.framework/RAMAnimatedTabBarController
    0x1008c0000 - 0x1008cbfff RandomColorSwift arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/RandomColorSwift.framework/RandomColorSwift
    0x1008e8000 - 0x1008f3fff SMDatePicker arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/SMDatePicker.framework/SMDatePicker
    0x100918000 - 0x100923fff SwiftCountryPicker arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/SwiftCountryPicker.framework/SwiftCountryPicker
    0x100948000 - 0x100977fff SwiftyJSON arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
    0x10099c000 - 0x1009c7fff TextFieldEffects arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/TextFieldEffects.framework/TextFieldEffects
    0x1009f4000 - 0x100a17fff pop arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/pop.framework/pop
    0x100a48000 - 0x100c47fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
    0x100e04000 - 0x100e0bfff libswiftCoreData.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
    0x100e18000 - 0x100e23fff libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
    0x100e44000 - 0x100e4bfff libswiftCoreImage.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
    0x100e64000 - 0x100e6bfff libswiftDarwin.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
    0x100e80000 - 0x100e87fff libswiftDispatch.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
    0x100e90000 - 0x100ecbfff libswiftFoundation.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
    0x100f18000 - 0x100f1ffff libswiftObjectiveC.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
    0x100f40000 - 0x100f4bfff libswiftUIKit.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
    0x100f6c000 - 0x100f73fff libswiftContacts.dylib arm64   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/4E1B71D2-149D-46DB-8C3C-E1859A2FF552/Overseas Learning.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib
    0x1200b8000 - 0x1200e7fff dyld arm64   /usr/lib/dyld
    0x182f5c000 - 0x182f5dfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x182f60000 - 0x182fb2fff libc++.1.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x182fb4000 - 0x182fd3fff libc++abi.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x182fd4000 - 0x183340fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x183344000 - 0x183348fff libcache.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x18334c000 - 0x183357fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x183358000 - 0x18335bfff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x18335c000 - 0x183363fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x183364000 - 0x1833bffff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x1833c0000 - 0x1833eefff libdispatch.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x1833f0000 - 0x1833f2fff libdyld.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x1833f4000 - 0x1833f4fff liblaunch.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x1833f8000 - 0x1833fcfff libmacho.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x183400000 - 0x183401fff libremovefile.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x183404000 - 0x18341afff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x18341c000 - 0x18341dfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x183420000 - 0x18349ffff libsystem_c.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x1834a0000 - 0x1834a3fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x1834a4000 - 0x1834a7fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
    0x1834a8000 - 0x1834a9fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x1834ac000 - 0x1834c2fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x1834c4000 - 0x1834ccfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x1834d0000 - 0x1834f2fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x1834f4000 - 0x183515fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x183518000 - 0x183534fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x183538000 - 0x183551fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x183554000 - 0x1835b7fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x1835b8000 - 0x1835c1fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x1835c4000 - 0x1835cefff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x1835d0000 - 0x1835d5fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x1835d8000 - 0x1835e0fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x1835e4000 - 0x1835e6fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x1835e8000 - 0x1835f8fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x1835fc000 - 0x183601fff libunwind.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x183604000 - 0x183604fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
    0x183608000 - 0x18362dfff libxpc.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x183630000 - 0x183835fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x183838000 - 0x183849fff libz.1.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x18384c000 - 0x183bccfff CoreFoundation arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x183bd0000 - 0x183be0fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x183be4000 - 0x183be4fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
    0x183be8000 - 0x183c59fff IOKit arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x183c5c000 - 0x183c7cfff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x183c80000 - 0x183d6afff libxml2.2.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x183d6c000 - 0x183ddefff Security arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
    0x183de0000 - 0x183e39fff SystemConfiguration arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
    0x183e3c000 - 0x183f24fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x183f28000 - 0x1841bcfff CFNetwork arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
    0x1841c0000 - 0x1841cdfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x1841d0000 - 0x1841e9fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
    0x1841ec000 - 0x184206fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x184208000 - 0x184232fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x184234000 - 0x184252fff libextension.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
    0x184254000 - 0x184255fff liblangid.dylib arm64   /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x184258000 - 0x1844c6fff Foundation arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x1844c8000 - 0x184573fff libBLAS.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
    0x184574000 - 0x1848d9fff libLAPACK.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x1848dc000 - 0x184b41fff vImage arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
    0x184b44000 - 0x184b66fff libvMisc.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
    0x184b68000 - 0x184b7bfff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x184b7c000 - 0x184b8bfff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
    0x184b8c000 - 0x184bf8fff libvDSP.dylib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
    0x184bfc000 - 0x184bfcfff vecLib arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
```

Comment: You could start by trying to symbolicate the crash log. To turn 'Overseas Learning               0x00000001000ed1d8 0x100078000 + 479704' in to readable method names. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to try several standard login behaviors.

I mean try to login if:

- user already is login in Facebook in safari
- facebook app is installed

Comment: Thx. I did all of this in my testing. And no crash at all

Comment: Have you use the same iOS version on devices?

Comment: Great point! Thx a lot. 9.3.5. just came out. I dont have installed that. Let me report back.

Comment: Was missing on iPhone. on iPad I had 9.3.5. no errors and works well. Its really tricky. I asked Apple to send me the console logs.

Comment: What version of Facebook SDK do you use? You can take a look submitted bug to Facebook developers, may be you'll find this crash

Comment: I got a reply from Apple and they told me now that they can use facebook for login. After I asked them for more details.